# Oracle select query does not fetch records where value is null

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an oracle DB query where I want to fetch all such records from a table where the value of DECISION
is not equal to DISCARD.
I ran the below query:

`select *  from TABLE where DECISION != 'Discard'`

I had two records in my database but for both the DECISION was null ,which is not equal to DISCARD. However, I did not get any record.

So, I had to change the query to below which fetched the records successfully.

`select *  from TABLE where (DECISION != 'Discard' or DECISION is null)`

I am confused about what is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `NVL`

```
select *  from TABLE where NVL(DECISION,'x') != 'Discard'
```

The "problem" is in the three value SQL logik

if `DECISION` is NULL than `DECISION != 'Discard'` returns not `TRUE` but `UNKNOWN` (it means it is not known if DECISION is `Discard` or not).

See details in [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm)

> a != NULL   gives UNKNOWN for any value of a

To get all rows testing a *nullable* column you must use `NVL` or possible `COALESCE` (= more "standard")

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Ashish Unfortunately not as simple. SQL implements a *three value logik* with `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`, so you can't imply *not true --> false*. See overview in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions004.htm)

Answer (score 2):

By design / definition, `NULL` is a special value indicating unknown/inapplicable.  Any comparison made to `NULL` is `UNKNOWN`, which in Oracle's three-valued logic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`.

Your 1st predicate:

```
where DECISION != 'Discard'
```

evaluates to `UNKNOWN` for records having a `NULL` decision.  The `WHERE` clause only includes rows where the predicate is `TRUE`.  Since `UNKNOWN` is not the same as `TRUE`, your 1st predicate excludes `NULL` values.

Your 2nd predicate:

```
where (DECISION != 'Discard' or DECISION is null)
```

Evaluates to `(UNKNOWN OR TRUE)`, which in turn evaluates to `TRUE`.  So, your 2nd predicate includes the `NULL` values.

Comment: This is **not correct** as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm). `1 = null` is  UNKNOWN and **not false**. If it would be *false* the negation of it (NOT) would be *true*, which it *is not*! Please adjust to not spread confusion in an already confusing logik;)